# DELETE works with serializable or repeatable read isolation levels or not

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008: I would like to put delete statement inside a ‘Transaction’ of which isolation level is set to ‘Repeatable Read’ or ‘Serializable’. I want to know if we can use DELETE in these isolation levels. 
The main question is, will the intended locks i.e. Locks only on the selected data will work with delete statement or will DELETE continue to use Table lock?

Comment: Any operation in SQL Server will use **row-level** locks by default (unless you've configured it differently). And yes, of course, you can use `DELETE` with **any** isolation level. The `DELETE` will only jump to a table-level lock if **(1)** you tell it to, or **(2)** you are trying to delete more than 5000 rows in a single transaction - in that case, SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and replace the 5000 single row-level locks by a single table-level lock

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the column(s) used to locate the row(s) to be deleted.  Otherwise, a full scan will be required which will be bad for concurrency in any transaction isolation level.

Comment: @DanGuzman : I am relatively new to indexing. As mentioned by marc_s, if we modify statement in such a way that it doesn't delete more than 5000 rows in a single transaction, even then will we need to use Indexing? Just FYI we have lakhs of records, that are deleted approx daily, so should we go for transaction mode or modify statement to delete 5000 rows in a single transaction?

Comment: @HimanshuSingla, index and query tuning will help both performance and concurrency even if you delete in batches.  Without a useful index, each `DELETE` will take progressively longer to execute as more rows are scanned and lock even those rows that are note to be deleted.  Note that lock escalation is deferred if the table-level lock can't be acquired due to a conflict.  Lock escalation will be attempted again after the next 1250 locks.